# Resizing problem of ActiveX - control, created in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, ms-access, activex

I am trying to create one simple ActiveX control in c# and ran into one unsolvable problem when applying them on forms in MS Access applications.

Namely, these controls are not resizable - neither programmatically, nor if you use anchors. Sometimes the control starts to change in size when you simply scroll the middle mouse wheel over it. I dug up the Internet and can not find any clue that would help in solving this problem.

For example, you can use the following implementation (I tried others - the problems with the sizes are the same): https://codedocu.com/Office-365/Office/COM-Controls/Code_colon_-Create-your-own-ActiveX-Component-in-Visual-Studio-2017-and-Office-2016-365?2075

Answer (score 3):

The solution is described in this answer: [.Net usercontrol in MS Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365583/net-usercontrol-in-ms-access)

Include this method in the COM interface and use it to resize:

```
public void ResizeThis (int width, int height)
{
  this.UpdateBounds (Left, Top, width, height);
  this.SetBounds (0, 0, width + 1, height + 1, BoundsSpecified.Width | BoundsSpecified.Height);
}
```